# JMeter - Non HTTP response message: URI can't be null

Tags: jmeter

I need to test a web login using jmeter but this is the response in the results tree:

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 1970-01-01 05:30:00 IST
Load time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 1089
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 1089
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: URI can't be null.
```

Response headers:

```
HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

can someone please help me?

Comment: Did you find solution to this issue? I am also facing this when I try to run JUnit script in JMeter.

Answer (score 3):

You entered a bad url in http sampler, check fields:

- host
- port
- path

Another option is to read:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Comment: Exactly, my problem was that I entered **Server Name or IP** with protocol prefix (http://). When I removed this prefix, everything works without problems. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not owner of this question, and so I don't have permissions to accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue resolved, in my own with several testing..
Try to open the file in notepad and check it,

Links should be in this format

"GET /

"GET /css/bootstrap.min.css

"GET /theme/css/daterangepicker/daterangepicker+AC0-bs3.css

and in the Access Log Sampler 
Server: works only on hosted site..example test.com if you enter ip. address for test.com it will not work based on my testing